# How to traverse an ansible list with a variable index?

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-2.x

There is a list as:

```
list:
  - zero
  - one
  - two
```

For which:

```
list.0 -> zero
list.1 -> one
list.2 -> two
```

Is there a way where we could use a variable instead of using 0,1,2, etc?

Something like we do in any high-level-programming language:

```
(In a loop from var=0 to var=2){
  print(list.var)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [range](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/latest/templates/#jinja-globals.range). For example

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    start: 0
    stop: 3
    list:
      - zero
      - one
      - two
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ list[item] }}"
      loop: "{{ range(start, stop) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => (item=0) => 
  msg: zero
ok: [localhost] => (item=1) => 
  msg: one
ok: [localhost] => (item=2) => 
  msg: two
```